# Trimming a variable and assigning to itself seems to not work

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a form field for which I am getting input like this:

```
 NSString *name = personName.text;
```

Then I am doing this:

```
NSString *name = [name stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

But the extra strings do not seem to disappear.  Am I doing something incorrectly? Is there a way to do the trim right when I get the field value without tripping on the case when input is nil so that an exception is not generated?

Thanks!

Comment: After you have created the new String with -stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet what do you do with it?

Comment: @hooleyhoop I send it to the database ....nothing too special :)

Comment: What do you mean "the extra strings do not seem to disappear"? Can you give an example of your input string, and what you get after the trimming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but I think you should not create "name" again. Just assign it directly. Like:
name = [name stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Answer (score 1):

The above code shouldn't be a problem when `name` is `nil`. Sending a message to `nil` is allowed in Objective-C and the result will be again `nil`. The problem has to be somewhere else. Probably somewhere after this part when you try to use the `name` otherwise, like adding it to an array or dictionary.

Consider replacing a `nil` `name` with an empty string.

```
if (!name) name = @"";
```